# Comparing strings with numbers - Python

Tags: python, string, compare

I can't figure out why the following code gives a True, False, True result.

```
print("3" < "4")
print("3" < "10")
print("3" < "30")
```

I understand the 1st and 3rd code but why doesn't the `print("3" < "10")` give a `True` response.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the python docs on [comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) operations:

> Strings are compared lexicographically using the numeric equivalents (the result of the built-in function ord()) of their characters.

The character comparison starts with the first character and steps through the strings being compared until a character difference is found.

Your 2nd statement returns `False` since:

```
ord("3") > ord ("1")
```

Answer (score 2):

The link suggested will give you elaborate answer. However since I am assuming that you are beginning programming, I am trying to take a very simple approach to explain.

For strings, as soon as you start writing:

```
 "ab"<"bc"

 "30"<"400"
```

Imagine this:

```
['a', 'b'] <['b', 'c']
['3', '0'] <['1', '0', '0']
```

Now the comparison is made on the first elements of both list and only moves to next element if they are equal:

The first one should be True.
The second one should be False.

Follow the same logic and try:

```
'30'<'31'
```

It should evaluate to True.